# declare library dependency in meson not found by pkg-config and cmake

Tags: c++, meson-build

This question is related to the meson build system, specifically how to add an external dependency (library) which is not found by pkg-config and / or cmake. This should be simple but it seems I am missing something (obvious?!).

Say I have a static library somewhere in a custom path `/home/user/libraries/foo/lib/libfoo.a` with a corresponding include directory `/home/user/libraries/foo/include/`. As this library is not found by pkg-config and / or cmake, doing something like

```
foo_dep = dependency('foo')
exe = executable('bar','bar.cpp', link_with: foo_dep)
```

will not work. So I am wondering what the *meson* way of doing things is, i.e. should I use `declare_dependency()` (although I thought that this is more for subprojects), should I pass compiler and linker flags with `-I` and `-L -l` etc. (although that would mean specifying hard links which may be maintained manually which can't be the preferred way) or is there a better way out there for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `find_library()` and `has_header()` methods on the compiler object: https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#compiler-object

Then pass that to whatever you are compiling.

```
cxx = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
libfoo = cxx.find_library('foo')
executable('foo', 'foo.cpp',
  link_with: libfoo,
  include_directories: ..., # Using has_header() find this path
)
```

Comment: thanks, I think I came across that solution somewhere but discarded it as it looked more like a hack. Anyways, makes sense, will use it.

Comment: just to add to that comment (after getting it to work), link_with is only for internal dependencies (in my case i have an external one, i.e. located in `/usr/local/`) so i have to use dependencies instead of link_with. Not sure how you would find an include directory using has_header() (which returns a boolean), but it is useful none-the-less to check if the header is present